# Minimizing a function of 2 variables which are probabilities

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, maxima-minima, numerical-optimization

I have a function $f(\vec{q})$, which I need to minimize, where $\vec{q} =(q_1,q_2)$.  Note that $q_1$ and $q_2$ are probability values. $n_1, n_2, k_1,k_2$ are positive natural numbers. Also, $n_1$ & $n_2$ values are much greater than $k_1$ & $k_2$ values.

\begin{aligned} f(\vec{q}) & \approx\left(n_{1}\right)\left(1-T q_{1}\left(1-q_{1}\right)^{k_{1}}\left(1-q_{2}\right)^{k_{2}}\right) \\ &+\left(n_{2}\right)\left(1-T q_{2}\left(1-q_{1}\right)^{k_{1}}\left(1-q_{2}\right)^{k_{2}}\right) \end{aligned}

I took the 2 partial derivatives and solved them simultaneously to obtain the following:
\begin{aligned} q_{1} &=\frac{n_{1}-n_{2} k_{1}+n_{1} k_{2}}{n_{1}\left(k_{1}+k_{2}+1\right)} \\ q_{2} &=\frac{n_{2}-n_{1} k_{2}+n_{2} k_{1}}{n_{2}\left(k_{1}+k_{2}+1\right)} \end{aligned}

Here is the problem I am facing:

> From the solutions I got, It seems that $q_1$ or $q_2$ can be negative for some choices of $n_1, n_2, k_1,k_2$, which is not acceptable as $q_1$ or $q_2$ are probability values.

In such cases, how do I find the minimum within the $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ domain. Shall I just check the values of the function at the boundary points. ? I tried that , but all boundary points lead to the same solution $n_1 +n_2$.

Can someone explain how I should go about this?

Comment: what does $f(\vec{q}) \approx$ mean?

Comment: @Joitandr, the function $f\vec(q)$ is approximated as the RHS

Answer (score 1):

You can use Lagrange multipliers technique:

$$\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
f(q_{1}, q_{2}) \to \min\limits_{q_{1}, q_{2}} \\
0 \le q_{1} \le 1 \\
0 \le q_{2} \le 1
\end{array}\right.$$

$L = f(q_{1}, q_{2}) - \lambda_{1} \cdot q_{1} + \lambda_{2} \cdot (q_{1} - 1) - \lambda_3 \cdot q_{2} + \lambda_4 \cdot (q_{2} - 1)$

And use [Karush-Kuhn-Tucker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions) conditions to minimize it:

K.K.T:

$$\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
L^{\prime}_{q_{1}} = 0 \\
L^{\prime}_{q_{2}} = 0 \\
\lambda_{1, 2, 3, 4} \ge 0 \\
\lambda_{1} \cdot q_{1} = 0 \\
\lambda_{2} \cdot (q_{1} - 1) = 0 \\
\lambda_{3} \cdot q_{2} = 0 \\
\lambda_{4} \cdot (q_{2} - 1) = 0 \\
\end{array}\right.$$

Comment: Is the L correct in your solution? Shouldn't it be (q1-1) and (q2-1) in the 3rd and 5th terms respectively.

Comment: you are right, thanks